# при перезаписи xml файла дозаписывается лишнее

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, сериализация

Проблема, что когда идет перезапись файла, в сам файл дозаписывает лишние символы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо может перезаписать в таком ключе `</ConnectionString>ctionString>`

Перезапись файла происходит при переключения пользователя

```
private void NewConnectionString()
        {
            FormChangeUser changeUser = new FormChangeUser();
            if (File.Exists("DataConnection.xml"))
            {
                var loadData = cs.LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");
                var saveLastId = new ConnectionString() { UserId = loadData.UserId, Host = loadData.Host, Database = loadData.Database, PWD = loadData.PWD, TypeDb = loadData.TypeDb, СurrentUser = usersComboBox.Text, LastId = userIdTextBox.Text };
                cs.SaveFile(saveLastId, "DataConnection.xml");
            }
        }
```

Сам метод создания и записи файла

```
public void SaveFile(object obj, string path)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                using (var fs = new FileStream("DataConnection.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(fs, obj);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("File not saved!");
            }
        }
```

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: как ведет себя код при отсутствии файла "DataConnection.xml"? Данные записываются корректно?

Comment: @МихаилКошкарёв да

Comment: Вместо `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` используйте `FileMode.Create`.

Comment: Первое что пришло в голову - при создании потока вы задаете FileMode - FileMode.OpenOrCreate, и соответственно он(поток) открывает файл и устанавливает позицию в начало файла и просто "переписывает" новыми байтами, а лишнее - это остатки предыдущего содержимого

Comment: благодарю за помощь